# How to use Apache Ignite as JSR 107 cache?

Tags: java, caching, ignite, jsr107

I figured out a JSR 107 cache would be configured as follows:

```
private final static CacheManager MANAGER =
             Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();
private final static Cache<Long, Map<Integer, BufferedImage>> CACHE;
private final static Cache<Long, Map<Integer, ImageIcon>> CACHE_SERIALIZABLE;
static {
    MutableConfiguration<Long, Map<Integer, BufferedImage>> config = new MutableConfiguration<>();
    MutableConfiguration<Long, Map<Integer, ImageIcon>> javaFXConfig = new MutableConfiguration<>();
    for(MutableConfiguration config0 : new MutableConfiguration[] {config, javaFXConfig}) {
        config0.setStoreByValue(false)
                .setStatisticsEnabled(true)
                .setExpiryPolicyFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(
                        new AccessedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.HOURS, 1))));
    }
    CACHE = MANAGER.createCache("cache",
            config);
    CACHE_SERIALIZABLE = MANAGER.createCache("cache-serializable",
            javaFXConfig);
}
```

However after adding

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

to `pom.xml` the cache doesn't store any values in the value-site `Map`s (an example is provided at https://github.com/krichter722/ignite-storage-failure).

I would like to run a local in-memory setup with embedded Ignite only. Unfortunately there's not one "Getting started"-documentation about this use case - only complicated distributed setups and non-JSR 107/Ignite-specific configuration.

Since this is the absolute easiest use case for a caching framework it, this has to be possible.

I'm using Apache Ignite 1.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

> config0.setStoreByValue(false)

Ignite has no store by reference support. See https://github.com/cruftex/jsr107-test-zoo/blob/master/report.md#apache-ignite-1x-test

Of course, it would be good to throw an exception, when this is tried.

Comment: I see. Using Ehcache's JCache 1.0.1 just works fine and there's no need to change the code, so I can recommend doing that.

Comment: Store by reference is an optional feature; throwing an exception when an optional feature is not present would be undesirable. The way to handle the "missing" feature is `if (MANAGER.getCachingProvider().isSupported(OptionalFeature.STORE_BY_REFERENCE)) config0.setStoreByValue(false);`